# Cant find ID of button

Tags: authentication, apify

I am trying to log in to strava.cz but I am unable to find id of the button. Is there some other way to initiate login?

So far I can write in the credentials, but I am unable to to find ID of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest workaround for this would be to simulate keypress anywhere on the form. Assuming you are using puppeteer and the form is focused after inserting the credentials and canteen ID: `page.keyboard.press('Enter')`

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-keyboardpresskey-options

Then you will need to wait for the login, e.g. by using

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selectors: **`form input[title="Přihlásit se"]`** or **`form .prihlaseni-prihlasit`**

To submit a form we usually use:

```
await Promise.all([
   page.click('form .prihlaseni-prihlasit'),
   page.waitForNavigation(),
])
```